# Why are all Windows 11 optional updates suddenly awaiting installation without possibility to deselect?

Tags: windows-update, windows-11, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

After Windows 11 update of November 9, 2022, all recent (30+) optional updates for my Lenovo ThinkPad are suddenly awaiting installation without any option to deselect.

Some of the updates are Intel system updates from 2017! Others are Logitec drivers from 2012 and Dell Inc. from 2015.

Even two outdated Lenovo Firmware.

It cannot be healty to install all these 30+ updates.

My laptop i a ThinkPad T14s Gen 1, which has its own Lenovo System Update.

Comment: You must have recently updated your system to Windows 11 22H2. They are optional updates for a reason.

Comment: I updated to Windows 11 several months ago. Many of the updates awaiting installation were outdated and from 2018. I guess the reason is an error in Windows Update.

Comment: Did you recently perform any action that would have wiped the Windows Update history on your machine? You installed Windows 11 21H2, several months ago, but what about Windows 22H2 which was only released last month?

Comment: I installed the recommended Windows Updates on November 9. Actually they were installed during nighttime. I only had to reboot the laptop in the morning. Unfortunately, the updates wiped the Wifi settings, which I had to restore manually.

Comment: I'm still on Windows 11 21H2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It cannot be healty to install all these 30+ updates.

Why?

Let it update.

Optional indicates that some updates may be necessary driver updates.

Windows 11 is continuing more firmly than ever to insist updates happen.

Use Windows Update settings to schedule Restart in off hours.  That works fine.

Some updates may go in groups and then re-update a day or so later.

While there may be issues with some specific computers, in general it is a good idea to allow updates to happen

Comment: Generally speaking, I agree. The issue in this case is that Lenovo System Update already has installed all necessary updates. However, Windows Update wants to install a lot of outdated updates that have already been taken care of by Lenovo System Update. If I installed all the outdated updates from Windows Update, my laptop would probably crash.

Comment: On my own Lenovo laptops, if Lenovo System Update installs drivers, Windows does not reinstall them. I am not sure why in your case. Also my laptops have not crashed when optional updates have been installed.

Comment: I took the risk and installed all the optional updates from Windows Update. My laptop didn't crash. It didn't even need a restart. Thanks for your advice.